# Android Flutter ABI Architecture Fallback

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, flutter

Currently I'm building a UnityPlayer-Plugin for Flutter. Therefore I include some external libraries as static libraries(Unity, Vuforia).
Integration into Flutter app brings problems.
As you can see in  [APK Analyzing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9iPG.png) when flutter builds the app its creates additional ABI architectures for

- x86 (only flutter.so)
- x86_64 (only flutter.so)
- arm_64-v8a (only flutter.so)
- armabi-v7a (not flutter.so, but all *.so from third party libs)

Currently Unity is not supporting x64 builds and I'm using a arm64-v8a device for testing. This device will automatically use arm64-v8a in jniLibs which only has flutter inside and no unity libraries.

What's the best way to get Unity libraries to x86 and armabi-v7a and 64 bit (arm_64-v8a,x86_64) devices use as fallback (armabi-v7a,x86).

First tries with gradle [Split APK's](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits) were overwritten bei flutter.gradle and I don't find a way to get the flutter.so to armabi-v7a.

In the end I would image something  like this.

- x86 (flutter.so, libunity.so, libVuforia.so,...) -> used by x86 devices
- armabi-v7a (flutter.so, libunity.so, libVuforia.so,...) -> armabi-v7a devices
- x86_64 (only flutter.so) -> use libunity.so, libVuforia.so,... from x86 as fallback
- arm_64-v8a (only flutter.so)-> libunity.so, libVuforia.so,... from  armabi-v7a as fallback

Hope my usecase is clear and hope to get feedback soon.